# How to use split columns in Spark with delimiter which is available in records also

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have below data set

```
Segment.organizationId|^|Segment.segmentId|^|SegmentType|^|SegmentName|^|SegmentName.languageId|^|SegmentLocalLanguageLabel|^|SegmentLocalLanguageLabel.languageId|^|ValidFromPeriodEndDate|^|ValidToPeriodEndDate|^|SegmentInactivationReasonCode|^|SegmentOrganizationId|^|IsShariaCompliant|^|IsCorporate|^|IsElimination|^|IsOther|^|InactiveReasonOtherDescription|^|InactiveReasonOtherDescription.languageId|^|IsOperatingSegment|^|SegmentFundbDescription|^|SegmentFundbDescription.languageId|^|SegmentTypeId|^|SegmentInactiveReasonId|^|FFAction|!|
4295876080|^|7|^|B|^|Test ||^|505074|^|jtrsu|^|505126|^|2010-03-31T00:00:00Z|^||^||^||^|False|^|False|^|False|^|False|^||^|505074|^|False|^||^|505074|^|3013618|^||^|I|!|
```

Here is my code

```
val df = sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "|").option("inferSchema","true").load("s3://trfsmallfffile/FinancialSegment/TEST")
```

But this does not give me correct output

Here is my output

```
+----------------------+-----------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------+----------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------+---------------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------------+-------------+-----------------------+--------+-------------+
|Segment_organizationId|Segment_segmentId|SegmentType|SegmentName|SegmentName_languageId|SegmentLocalLanguageLabel|SegmentLocalLanguageLabel_languageId|ValidFromPeriodEndDate|ValidToPeriodEndDate|SegmentInactivationReasonCode|SegmentOrganizationId|IsShariaCompliant|IsCorporate|IsElimination|IsOther|InactiveReasonOtherDescription|InactiveReasonOtherDescription_languageId|IsOperatingSegment|SegmentFundbDescription|SegmentFundbDescription_languageId|SegmentTypeId|SegmentInactiveReasonId|FFAction|DataPartition|
+----------------------+-----------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------+----------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------+---------------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------------+-------------+-----------------------+--------+-------------+
|            4295876080|                7|          B|      Test |                     ^|                        ^|                                   ^|                     ^|                   ^|                            ^|                    ^|                ^|          ^|            ^|      ^|                             ^|                                        ^|                 ^|                      ^|                                 ^|            ^|                      ^|       ^|        Japan|
+----------------------+-----------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------+----------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------+---------------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------------+-------------+-----------------------+--------+-------------+
```

I am getting this because there is `|` character is used in the record .

How can i handle this situation?

My expected output is below

```
...+----------------------+-----------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------+----------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------+---------------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------------+-------------+-----------------------+-----------+
|Segment.organizationId|Segment.segmentId|SegmentType|SegmentName|SegmentName.languageId|SegmentLocalLanguageLabel|SegmentLocalLanguageLabel.languageId|ValidFromPeriodEndDate|ValidToPeriodEndDate|SegmentInactivationReasonCode|SegmentOrganizationId|IsShariaCompliant|IsCorporate|IsElimination|IsOther|InactiveReasonOtherDescription|InactiveReasonOtherDescription.languageId|IsOperatingSegment|SegmentFundbDescription|SegmentFundbDescription.languageId|SegmentTypeId|SegmentInactiveReasonId|FFAction|
+----------------------+-----------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------+----------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------+---------------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------------+-------------+-----------------------+-----------+
|4295876080            |7                |B          |Test |     |505074                |jtrsu                    |505126                              |2010-03-31T00:00:00Z  |                    |                             |                     |False            |False      |False        |False  |                              |505074                                   |False             |                       |505074                            |3013618      |                       |I       |
+----------------------+-----------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------+----------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------+---------------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------------+-------------+-----------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: you cannot use two character for the delimiter. thats not supported in spark sql

Comment: @RameshMaharjan updated my question please have a look once

Comment: you should go with sparkContext for using multiple character delimiter and convert the rdd to dataset or dataframe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple characters for *delimiter* is not supported in *spark sql* in `option` parameter. So I would suggest you to go with `sparkContext` as there is `split` function which supports multiple characters.

So your first step is to read the file using `sparkContext`

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("s3://trfsmallfffile/FinancialSegment/TEST")
```

Then you would need to separate the first line for the header and create `schema` from it

```
val header = rdd.filter(_.contains("Segment.organizationId")).map(line => line.split("\\|\\^\\|")).first()
val schema = StructType(header.map(cols => StructField(cols.replace(".", "_"), StringType)).toSeq)
```

Last step would be to create the required `dataframe` using the `schema` created

```
val data = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd.filter(!_.contains("Segment.organizationId")).map(line => Row.fromSeq(line.split("\\|\\^\\|").toSeq)), schema).show(false)
```

You should have following `dataframe`

```
+----------------------+-----------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------+----------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------+---------------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------------+-------------+-----------------------+-----------+
|Segment_organizationId|Segment_segmentId|SegmentType|SegmentName|SegmentName_languageId|SegmentLocalLanguageLabel|SegmentLocalLanguageLabel_languageId|ValidFromPeriodEndDate|ValidToPeriodEndDate|SegmentInactivationReasonCode|SegmentOrganizationId|IsShariaCompliant|IsCorporate|IsElimination|IsOther|InactiveReasonOtherDescription|InactiveReasonOtherDescription_languageId|IsOperatingSegment|SegmentFundbDescription|SegmentFundbDescription_languageId|SegmentTypeId|SegmentInactiveReasonId|FFAction|!||
+----------------------+-----------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------+----------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------+---------------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------------+-------------+-----------------------+-----------+
|4295876080            |7                |B          |Test |     |505074                |jtrsu                    |505126                              |2010-03-31T00:00:00Z  |                    |                             |                     |False            |False      |False        |False  |                              |505074                                   |False             |                       |505074                            |3013618      |                       |I|!|       |
+----------------------+-----------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------+----------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------+---------------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------------+-------------+-----------------------+-----------+
```